# .htaccess Issue : 404 for index

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my `.htaccess` file in `sub-folder`...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) ./index.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want `mydomain.com/sub-folder/string` to processed by index.php as `mydomain.com/sub-folder/?id=string`

But I am getting 404... not sure why. This is my root `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your root .htaccess as:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(index\.php|sub-folder(/.*)?)$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And keep this in `/sub-folder/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-folder/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```